# Does CoffeeScript allow JavaScript-style == equality semantics?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I love that [CoffeeScript compiles `==` into the JavaScript `===` operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators). But what if you want the original JS `==` semantics? Are they available? I've pored over the documentation and can't find anything enabling this.

More generally, is there a way to inline plain JS into my CoffeeScript code so that the compiler doesn't touch it?

I'd prefer to avoid editing the compiled JavaScript output, since I'm using [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) to auto-generate it in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do you need `==` ?  The accepted way to do this stuff is via explicit coercion.  `a.toString() === b.toString()` or `parseInt(a, 10) === parseInt(b, 10)`.  `==` is not to be trusted except for a very few specific cases that arguably should be handled for you by the coffee script compiler.

Comment: @Squeegy - Partly an academic question, actually, but I was mostly looking for a shorter form of `parseInt(a, 10) === parseInt(b, 10)`.

Comment: @Joseph - "Pored" is a word, and it doesn't mean the same as "poured".

Comment: My point is simply to say that most coffee scripters would insist that using backticks is "doing it wrong".  But if you are cool with that, go crazy :)

Comment: @Justin `+a === +b` will do what you want in that example. Nice little trick to have up your sleeve. :)

Comment: @TrevorBurnham this should be a standalone answer. It's excellent!

Comment: the `CoffeeScript compiles == into the JavaScript === operator.` link is dead

Comment: @TrevorBurnham That's not really equivalent unless you know `a` and `b` contain integer values. For instance, `parseInt('2.3', 10) === parseInt('2.4', 10)` is true, but `+'2.3' === +'2.4'` is false.

Comment: @SeantheBean is exactly right, and I would add that there are still differences in the case of `parseFloat`. For example, `parseFloat("", 10)` evaluates to `NaN`, but `+""` evaluates to 0. Depending on the application, that could be a problem.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> As a possible extension to this, is there a way to inline blocks of regular JS into CoffeeScript code so that it isn't compiled?

Yes, [here's the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded). You need to wrap the JavaScript code in backticks (`` ` ``). This is the only way for you to directly use JavaScript's `==` in CoffeeScript.  For example:

CoffeeScript Source <sup>[[try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%20%60a%20==%20b%60%0A%20%20console.log%20%22#%7Ba%7D%20equals%20#%7Bb%7D!%22)]</sup>

```
if `a == b`
  console.log "#{a} equals #{b}!"
```

Compiled JavaScript

```
if (a == b) {
  console.log("" + a + " equals " + b + "!");
}
```

---

The specific case of `== null`/`undefined`/`void 0` is served by the postfix existential operator `?`:

CoffeeScript Source <sup>[[try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:x%20=%2010%0Aconsole.log%20x?)]</sup>

```
x = 10
console.log x?
```

Compiled JavaScript

```
var x;
x = 10;
console.log(x != null);
```

CoffeeScript Source <sup>[[try it](http://coffeescript.org/#try:#%20%60x%60%20is%20not%20defined%20in%20this%20script%20but%20may%20have%20been%20defined%20elsewhere.%0Aconsole.log%20x?)]</sup>

```
# `x` is not defined in this script but may have been defined elsewhere.
console.log x?
```

Compiled JavaScript

```
var x;
console.log(typeof x !== "undefined" && x !== null);
```

Comment: Perfect. The `\`` wrapper is just what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the existential operator.  I was looking for == semantics for exactly that case.

Comment: Just a note, this conflicts with Coffescript's => block syntax and the `this` keyword. If you put `this` inside the ticks, you need to change it to _this or bypass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly the answer but this problem came up for me because jQuery's .text() was including whitespace and 'is' was failing in Coffeescript. Get around it by using jQuery's trim function:

```
$.trim(htmlText) is theExpectedValue
```